# how to get product list by category in nopcommerce using ajax?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

I'm using `nopCommerce` `version 4.20`. I want to get a product list using `ajax` and display category product page and I want to create `ajax` filter on the product page.

Comment: What have you tried? Share with us please.

Comment: You have to create a controller that provides this data (available attributes for filtering and filtered products) for you. By the way, consider that it will be a hard task to create such a functionality!

Comment: It's a big project! You can try by yourself and make your solution for it, and ask your questions finally.